# '$' symbol in typescript class

Tags: javascript, typescript

Why the '$' symbol is not recognized in typescript, since it is a super set of javascript? When I type for example `$('#example')` I have this error

> Cannot find name '$'

but in the javascript file everything is ok and it works. Otherwise I'd like to know whether the function `document.getElementById("something")` has the same meaning, so I can replace easly the '$' symbol.

Comment: $ is jquery symbol you need to add jquery reference if you need to use it

Comment: no, but neither in javascript, even though you can use it

Comment: @user3811714 how is possible to add jquery reference in typescript? And why in javascript it works although there is no reference (I guess)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely because you have not added jquery. Since that is *usually* what the `$` sign refers too. If you have, then add the definition from typescript definitions [here](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) at the top of the file.

Comment: After taking a look many web pages, I found out that '$' symbol and document.getElementById() or document.createElement() have the same meaning for my purposes, thus I could not import anything. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript cannot 'know' that $ stands for jQuery as it is not running in your browser. If it is jQuery put a reference to the [definition file](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/jquery):

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
```

As to your comment you indeed do not need jQuery for simple selectors.